# Guess the number app does not work as expected

Tags: haskell

The following piece of code should implement a simple guess the number game

```hs
import           Control.Monad (unless)
import           System.Random (Random (randomR), StdGen, getStdGen)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- getStdGen
  askForANumber gen

askForANumber :: StdGen -> IO ()
askForANumber gen = do
  let (randNumber, gen) = randomR (1, 10) gen :: (Int, StdGen)
  putStrLn "La ce numar intre 1 si 10 ma gandesc?"
  numberString <- getLine

  unless (null numberString) $ do
    let number = read numberString

    if randNumber == number
      then putStrLn "Ai ghicit!"
      else putStrLn $ "Imi pare rau era " ++ show randNumber

    askForANumber gen
```

The output is a surprising for me, but I am a beginner

[image]

If I replace line 7 with

```
askForANumber (mkStdGen 42)
```

All seems to work fine, so the problem seems to be `getStdGen`, what am I missing?

EDIT:

The mistake was on this line

```
  let (randNumber, gen) = randomR (1, 10) gen :: (Int, StdGen)
```

It used the gen recursively as @chi in comments pointed out

Replaced it with

```
  let (randNumber, newGen) = randomR (1, 10) gen :: (Int, StdGen)
```

And all works as expected.

Comment: `let (randNumber, gen) = randomR (1, 10) gen ` -- don't do that, it recursively defines `gen`. Use instead `let (randNumber, gen') = randomR (1, 10) gen` and use `gen'` below. Also, turn on warnings so that GHC helps identifying these mistakes!

Comment: Take a look at [`readMaybe @Int`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) for checking if the user input is a number. And instead of passing the generator you can use [`randomRIO (1, 10)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRIO) since you are already operating in IO.